# The fastest way to find the smallest positive root of the following transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

What is the **fastest way** to find the smallest positive root of the following transcendental equation:

$$a + b\cdot e^{-0.045 t} = n \sin(t) - m \cos(t)$$

```
eq = a + b E^(-0.045 t) == n Sin[t] - m Cos[t];
```

where 
$a,b,n,m$ are some real constants.

for instance I tried :

```
eq = 5  E^(-0.045 t) + 0.1 == -0.3 Cos[t] + 0.009 Sin[t];

sol = FindRoot[eq, {t, 1}]

{t -> 117.349}
```

There is an answer but  it doesn't mean that this is the smallest positive root ))

I don't like `FindRoot[]` because you need starting point, for different initial parameters  $(a,b,n,m)$

Is there a way to find the **smallest positive root** of equation for any $(a,b,n,m)$ (if there exist the solution), without *starting points*?

If No.  how to determine automatically starting point for a given parameters?

there is a numerical and graphical answers in *Wolfram Alpha*

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the values you have chosen are sensible. The left hand side is of size about 11 and the right hand size oscillates between +/-1.2. How can they be equal? If you change $a$ to 1, you get an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Amplifying on comment by @bills; for your specific example there are no roots

```
eq = 11 + 5 E^(-0.045 t) == 0.03 Sin[t] - 1.2 Cos[t] // Rationalize;
```

The [`FunctionRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html) of the LHS and RHS of the equation do not intersect

```
FunctionRange[#, t, y] & /@ List @@ eq // N

(* {y > 11., -1.20037 <= y <= 1.20037} *)
```

Or look at the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eq], {t, 0, 100},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.45}]]
```

[image]

For values of the parameters for which the plots intersect, the `Plot` will provide an initial value for [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) or constraint for use with [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html).

```
eq = 1 + 5 E^(-0.045 t) == 0.03 Sin[t] - 1.2 Cos[t] // Rationalize;

Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eq], {t, 60, 100},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[eq, {t, 72}]

(* {t -> 72.1339} *)

NSolve[{eq, 60 < t < 80}, t][[1]]

(* {t -> 72.1339} *)
```

Note that for `NSolve` the constraint can be loose; whereas, for `FindRoot` the initial estimate must be closer to the actual value.

Comment: ok, good. but this is not a "fast way" because you need starting point  in  FindRoot[] (72). why 72 and not 73 ??  how do you know the numerical value of starting point?

Comment: @vito - As stated above, you use the `Plot` to get an initial estimate for `FindRoot`.  A value on the leading edge of the yellow curve will work, e.g., anything between `69.9` to `72.1`. Zoom in on the `Plot`to get a better view. `Plot[Evaluate[List@@eq], {t, 69, 73}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` A tight initial estimate is unnecessary if you use `NSolve`. The range for `NSolve` can be very broad, e.g., `NSolve[{eq, 0 < t < 1000}, t][[1]]` will give the smallest positive root since `Part` is used to take the smallest value.

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = 1 + 5 E^(-0.045 t) - (0.03 Sin[t] - 1.2 Cos[t]);
```

To find the first root,  plot the equation and marker the roots.

```
Plot[eq, {t, 50, 150}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize@Medium]]
```

[image]

The first root lies between 70 < t < 75

```
NSolve[eq == 0 && 70 < t < 75, t]
{{t -> 72.1339}, {t -> 72.3439}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by hand for to isolate the root. The following identity is helpful:

```
n Sin[t] - m Cos[t] == Sqrt[m^2 + n^2] Cos[t - ArcTan[-m, n]]
```

Then you can figure out that the earliest to start your search is here:

```
Solve[a + b E^(-45/1000 t) == Sqrt[m^2 + n^2], t, Reals]
```

Then you just have to deal with the different cases (intersects one to three times in the first period where there are intersections):

```
Block[{b = 5, a = 0.1, m = 0.3, n = 0.009},
 (* Assumes b > 0 and a < Sqrt[m^2+n^2] *)
 Module[{tmax, t0, t1, tcrit, t2, y0, y2},
  tmax = Mod[ArcTan[-m, n], 2 Pi];
  t0 = 200/9 Log[b/(-a + Sqrt[m^2 + n^2])];
  t1 = Floor[t0 - tmax, 2 Pi] + tmax;
  tcrit = 
   Mod[ArcSin[Min[(9 b E^(-9 t1/200))/(200 Sqrt[m^2 + n^2]), 1]] + 0 ArcTan[-m, n], 2 Pi];
  t2 = t1 + tcrit;
  With[{y = Subtract @@ eq},
   y0 = y /. t -> t0;
   y2 = y /. t -> t2
   ];
  Which[
   y0 == 0, {t -> t0},
   y2 == 0, {t -> t2},
   y0*y2 < 0, FindRoot[eq, {t, (t0 + t2)/2, t0, t2}],
   True, FindRoot[eq, {t, (t1 + 3 Pi/2), t1 + Pi, t1 + 2 Pi}]
   ]
  ]]

(*  {t -> 72.0486}  *)
```

For `{b = 5, a = 0.0775, m = -0.3, n = 0.009}`, we get

```
{t -> 69.1481}
```

For `{b = 1, a = 0, m = -1, n = 0}`, we get

```
{t -> 0}
```

The other measure-zero case is harder to achieve.

Hopefully I didn't make any fence-post type errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that requires no plotting or guessing of initial points. It uses `FindInstance` to find successively smaller solutions until no smaller solution can be found.

```
try[tt_] := With[{r = FindInstance[eq && t < tt, t, Reals]},
   If[r == {}, tt, t /. r[[1]]]]
FixedPoint[try, Infinity]
(* 72.0486 *)
```